# acessing variables from one class to another in swift

Tags: swift

In the app the user types in infomations as integers into two different textfields. After a action button click the user now access two other textfields which the user again types data as integers. Now after a click on a button I want a label's text to show this typed in information from the two situations earlier

However in my code, I can't access my variables (the information from the user input) because this label's text is in a new class and the user input variables are stored in two other classes).

How can I access these variables in my new class where my label is?

An example of my code:

```
 @IBOutlet var nextStagetwo: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func check(sender: AnyObject) {

    var strValue = boxShots.text
    var floatValue = Double((strValue as! NSString).integerValue)
    var strValue2 = boxMakes.text
    var floatValue2 = Double((strValue2 as! NSString).integerValue)
    var stage = "stage 2"
    var procent = floatValue2 / floatValue * 100
enter code here
```

I now want to access my variable `procent` in this class:

```
class stagethree: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var stats: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func check(sender: AnyObject) {

 // this is where I want to write:  stats.text = "\(procent)"
// however I can't, because it doesn't register the variable "procent" because it is in another class.
```

Comment: Add code you have now to be able to help you a concrete example

Comment: @alex_p now updated with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either make a global store that stores the values for you

```
struct Store {
    static var valueOne:Int? 
}
```

and then in your view controllers you can set those values

```
Store.valueOne = 1
```

Other option would be to send those integers to the next view controller in your

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondController {
        destinationController.valueOne = valueOne
    }
}
```

Comment: would you mind elaborating on the global store? I'm not sure I understand it completely. for example  Store.valueOne = 1

Maybe im just being a really rookie here, im sorry!

Comment: So basically is just static values in a struct. You can set whatever value you want to save from the first view controller like that `Store.valueOne = [the value]` and the get it in the third view controller where you wanted to display it. `var storedValue = Store.valueOne`. Just make a new file and put the first 3 lines of code in that file. Then you can save and fetch values from it in all your view controllers.

Comment: I think I understand it now, however how will this be able to get fetched into my new class? won't it be the exact same thing when I just store a regular variable inside the first class? and then it can't be set in to the next one? (I must be missing the whole concept right in front of my eyes, I'm am sorry for that sir!) Appreciate the help!

Comment: I saw a video explaining "prepareForSegue" and I got it to work. Thanks for the help!